# PHP Contact Form Does Not Confirm Sent Message

Tags: php, contact-form

After a one-page website redesign, I've noticed that the contact form is not working correctly. It accepts input, but then the page doesn't reload. The PHP confirmation messages are also visible even before you click "submit". I also do not get an email with the collected data. I copied this PHP from the previous working contact form in the old version of my website, and am trying to get it to fit into the new code. I've matched up all of the variables and checked it for spelling errors. So far, I don't see any differences in the code, but it obviously doesn't work. ?

In the error log, the code says:

```
[24-Jan-2015 15:07:54 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '(' in /home/website/public_html/index.php on line 664
```

Listen 664 is the line below that begins "

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Contact Form'; 
$to = 'me@email.com'; 
$subject = 'Inquiry';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message:\n $message";

if ($name != '' && $email != '')
 {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from))
    {
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent.</p>';
    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again.</p>'; 
    }
 }  
else 
{
      echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields.</p>';
}
}
?>
```

Here is all the contact form:

```
<div class="col-md-6 contact-form">
<h1>Get In touch</h1>
<div class="contact" data-scroll-reveal="enter left">
<form id="contact-form" action="index.php" method="post">
<ul>
<li>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
</li>
<li>
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" placeholder="Number">
</li>
<li>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
</li>
<li>
<textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message">   </textarea>
<input class="btnsend" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
</li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your curly braces aren't balanced. Did you copy the code correctly?

Comment: You should place all the php in a block that checks if a POST request was made. Assuming that all you have shown is part of the same page / script...

Comment: Yes that is ALL the PHP.

Comment: I notice that you are pointing the form to index.php `action="index.php"`. Is this intended? Is the php code you posted in a file called index.php?

Comment: No, this file is index.php. The contact form is at the bottom of the landing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your code into the if, as @jeroen said, use isset and you can also put the last else for your `if ($name`, like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: Blue Mountain Website Contact Form'; 
    $to = 'cassidy@blumount.com'; 
    $subject = 'Inquiry';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Phone: $phone\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent.</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again.</p>'; 
        }
    }  else {
        echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields.</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: If this were the real problem he'd get a blank page. It's probably a copying error on SO.

Comment: I'd add also in your script to check if these POST are set and if they are not empty. Good error checking yourself will lead to less issues in the long run.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately the PHP code still displays on the page above the contact form before hitting "submit", I don't get an email, and the page doesn't reload to show the confirmation message.

Comment: Strange. Do you have another `_POST` vars before this part?

Comment: I just updated my original posting to include the revised code...this is all the PHP and the contact form.

Comment: Ok, what's been displayed before the form submit? Try, after the first if(, to put a `var_dump($_POST)` and see if returns anything.

Comment: Now it seems to not be showing the PHP on the website, but I'm not receiving a successful email. It displayed "NULL" after making the var_dump change and filling out the form. ? You can see it in action here [link](http://blumount.com)

Comment: Oh, your submit button doesn't have a name. Just the ID won't isset it. Try this: `<input class="btnsend" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send">`

Comment: Aha! Thank you! That's what I was missing. I added the name, then switched out the var_dump for the isset. Works perfectly, shows confirmation message on the page and I get the email.